# Is there an inspection in PHPStorm that detects JavaScript debugging-only code?

Tags: javascript, debugging, phpstorm, console.log

When I've finished debugging an issue, occasionally, one or two `console.log()` calls and `debugger;` statements go unnoticed, and end up in source control as a result, which I'd like to avoid.

Is there an inspection that would detect this, and maybe even allow setting its severity (e.g. to treat it like an error), similar to other inspections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections`
2. `JavaScript | JavaScript validity issues`
3. `'debugger' statement`

> This inspection reports JavaScript 'debugger' statements, used for interaction with Javascript debuggers. Such statements should probably not be found in production code.

Unfortunately I do not know about similar inspection for `console` statements.

**P.S.**
If it would be a PHP code .. it could be done via "Php Inspections (EA Extended)" plugin where in similar by functionality inspection you can provide your own functions/classes.

Answer (score 2):

To detect `console.log` calls, it's possible to create a Structural Search Inspection, found under `Editor > Inspections > General > Structural Search Inspection`. After enabling it, you need to click the **+** icon in the bottom half of the right side, and pick "Add Search template…".

[image: Add Search template for structural search]

Then, use the following settings:

- Use `console.log($log$);` as `Search template`
- Tick `Case-sensitive`
- Select `JavaScript` as the `File type`

[image: Structural Search Inspection example with console.log]

And finally, click OK, and give your new inspection a name that will be shown when it matches, e.g. "Console logging detected".

[image: Structural search inspection in its natural habitat]